# React renders old output from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component called `Polls` which fetches the polls from a REST API.

```js
function Polls (props){
    const [pollQuestion, setPollQuestion] = useState()
    const [pollOptions, setPollOptions] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    ...
}
```

The useEffect hook sets the loading property to true and then initiates the `loadPolls()` method

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        loadPolls()
    }, [props])
```

The `loadPolls()` method fetches the data from the REST API. The API fetches the data based on the `Token` that is passed in the header. So I call this method while logging in and also while logging out.

```js
    const loadPolls = (async () => {
        await fetch("http://localhost:3003/poll", 
        {
            method : "GET",
            headers : {"Accept": "application/json",
                       "Content-Type": "application/json",
                       "Token": sessionStorage.getItem('user')
                      }
        }
        ).then(res => res.json()).then (res => 
                {
                    if ('question' in res['data']) 
                        setPollQuestion(res['data']['question'])
                    if ('options' in res['data']) 
                        setPollOptions(res['data']['options'])
                    setLoading(false)
                })
    })
```

The expectation is that when the login is successful, the relevant polls must be displayed and when we log off, the polls must be empty in the screen. I did check the return data from the API and it sends polls data when there is a valid Token and empty dict when the Token is empty.

However the render component shows the Polls when I login, but even when I log off, the polls are still visible.

```js
    return (
        <>
            {loading ? 
                <p> Loading...</p>
            :
            <>
                <div className='pollquestion'> 
                    {pollQuestion}
                </div>
                <div className='pollOptions'>
                    { pollOptions.map( (i) => {
                            return (<div key={i} className='pollOption'> {i} 
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </>
            }
        </>
    )
```

But, when I refresh the page after logging off, the screen becomes empty - which is the expected behaviour. Can someone help me figure out the problem here, please?

Thanks.

Comment: You're only ever calling `setPollQuestion` if there's a question in the response. You need to set it to null at some point for it to go away.

Comment: To add what @lucasvw said, when there is no `user` reset the `poll` states. It's debatable whether its is necessary to perform the API call when `user` doesn't exist.